# BigQuery long running - ARRAY_AGG

Tags: google-bigquery

We are executing below query to identify the latest record based on key value against table size >1.4 TB but query is taking more than 20 mins for completion. Upon checking the execution details - compute step is consuming more time

```sql
select 
  row.col1,
  row.col2,
  row.col3... 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY t.timestamp  DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS ROW
   FROM [mytable] t 
   group by co11, col2, col3, col4)
```

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Off topic: you can do `SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY t.first DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]` instead of introducing `select row.*`

Comment: Can you share your table schema? I don't understand the query.

Comment: What is the size of the query output here? I would expect faster execution if the number of unique (col1, col2, col3, col4) combinations is low (compared to total number of rows) and the output is small. But if most combinations are unique and output is around ~1TB as well, 20 min might be a reasonable time. Performance as usual depends also on if you use reservations, concurrent queries, specific region, etc.

Comment: Objective is to get latest record based on key columns 

Schema -
Col1 Integer
Col2 Integer
Col3 String
Col4 String
Col5 String
Col6 String
Col7 String
Col8…Col99 String
Col100 String
timestamp Datetime


Total records - 2265683330
Table Size - 1.49 TB